# How can I use a space as a delimiter for this code

Tags: c

I use the following to split my strings into usable information

```
sscanf(last, "%*[^:]:%*[^:]:%*[^:]:%127[^:]:", field_x);
```

which would grab the fourth field of a string separated by colons, but now I need to use it to split a string separated by spaces, but I have no clue how to do it as doing throwing " "'s in place of the colons would not work, neither did replacing it with a \t work either, if someone could point me in the right direction for this I would really appreciate it (also I saw an example for strtok, but feel this type of string splitter is much easier to control in this instance) thanks!

Comment: Not really an answer, but have you considered using a good string library instead? Something like [bstring](http://bstring.sf.net/)?

Comment: I think we need example in- and output.

Comment: @sr42 would the string libraries be able to something like this without becoming terribly complicated? being that I have about 7-8 different strings that I need to split, and with something like strtok, the amount of code would be enormous :/

Comment: @NiklasB. the input code would look like so: 2011-10-27 03:43:46:176:84:1:nether:pvp_meep and then the output would be 176

Comment: @lacrosse1991 it depends on how complex you want to get. If all you're doing is splitting a string by spaces, then bstring provides a bsplit() function that will, in one call, split the string and return the tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what you believe,

```
sscanf(last, "%*[^ ] %*[^ ] %*[^ ] %127[^ ] ", field_x);
```

indeed [does what you want](http://ideone.com/34bB0)

Comment: thanks! Dont know why I had overlooked that one, had just been using a space between parentheses instead of the space by itself